# facebook ui feed picture taken from facebook not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

if i give picture:any other hosted image(eg:"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg") that will work fine.. but the following picture not working.. please help

```
  $FB.ui(
           { 
            method : 'feed',
            name: head,
            caption: '',
            description: desc,
            picture:'https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-prn1/t1/c28.28.355.355/s200x200/945291_160323350810130_2132651521_n.jpg' ,
            link: site link,  
            to: userid
                  },
          function (response) {
                }
        );
```

Comment: there's `picture:''` (missing quotes). Probably typo here, but your real code might have it. Make corrections to your question perhaps.

Comment: that is not the problem..:(

Comment: check the permissions .:-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this works only with images hosted outside of FB.

Comment: then how an app can post on a users wall with that users profile picture.. ?

Comment: I don't really understand, if you post to another user's wall, your profile picture will be shown anyway, or what do you exactly mean?

Comment: in the question i simply put the picture field as my profile pic just for example. but actually there i need the users profile picture. thank you